# Learning at chuppa

Tags: torah-study, chupah

Attending chuppahs in general seems to be a waste of time... Admittedly this may be a somewhat hashkafic question as opposed to halachic, but is it right, fitting or polite to learn from a pocket sefer during a chuppah?

Is there, for example, any quote that would imply that this is correct behaviour?

I think we have to consider יוהרא - religious arrogance and whether it is simply disrespectful to the marrying couple.

Advice on other, perhaps more polite ways of efficiently using chuppah time are also a solution to the issue...

Comment: Why not? Is there prohibitions

Comment: @kouty I dont think there is any explicit issur derabanan or deoraysa.... but is it the right thing to do?

Comment: Make sure you have a חבורה prepared, and tell it over to someone else while waiting, or review it yourself.

Comment: Most Chuppot are (for better or worse) great opportunities to teach people about the proper way to say Sheva Berakhot.

Comment: I question your 1st sentence. There are numerous halachot as well as examples of rabbanim mentioned in the Talmud that went out of their way to gladden the chattan and kallah. I think that attending the chuppah is part of fulfilling that mitzvah. Can you explain why you belive this is a waste of time?

Comment: @DanF My personal attendance will probably make very little, if any, difference to the happiness of חתן וכלה. The gemara's examples are of those who did solo dances etc. I'm not going to be doing that...

Comment: @DanF How does focusing at the chuppah make them happy? The question is do you need to focus. I could care less who paid attention at my chuppah besides my wife and the witnesses.

Comment: @DoubleAA Is it me? Where is the word "focus" in the question?

Comment: @DanF Someone can learn and still be at the Chuppah. All that would be missing is his paying attention to the Chuppah. But who cares about that? You haven't shown that paying attention at the Chuppah is important at all or that any rabbi ever has done so. Your above comment seems to completely miss the point of the question.

Comment: @DoubleAA Only from the answer, below, am I first understanding what was meant by "waste of time". This was really vague, IMO. I thought it meant that it's a waste of time to even attend in the first place.

Comment: @Dan He's trying to find more productive things to do at the chuppah. I don't see what's unclear about the question post at all.

Answer (score 2):

Rav Chaim Volozhiner quoted in Keser Rosh (16) quotes his Rebbe The Vilna Gaon that nowadays the prohibition of Yuharah does not apply nowadays. And that on the contrary, others should see you and learn from you. He only adds that this should be done lishma - for the sake of heaven with pure intentions. But that one should not be worried about others opinions of you.

Though the above Gr”a is not a unanimously agreed upon opinion. I personally have seen many great Scholars learning at the chuppa/other Smachot so as not to waste time, perhaps there actions were based on the Gr”a. The Gedolim that I have personally witnessed are:

Rav Moshe Sternbuch Shlit”a

Rav Asher Arieli Shlit”a

Rav Avigdor Nevenzahl Shlit”a

Rav Yitzchok Berkowitz Shlit”a

Regarding the feelings of the  chosson and kallah I think that is very subjective and one cannot presume their feelings. Some may appreciate that people are using their time wisely. Furthermore, it also depends on how conspicuous you are eg. is the book a pocket Sefer that may not be noticed? Or is it a large book that is noticeable to many? Are you standing in the back or in the front? Are you reading out loud or quietly reading? Maybe people will assume you are reading Tehillim, which is very common nowadays to give out parts of sefer tehillim to be said for the zchus of the chosson and kallah

Rav Henoch Leibowitz Zt"l, the Rosh Yeshiva of Chofetz Chaim, in a Hashkafa Shmuess in 1993 said that to learn from a sefer during the Chuppa would be a problem of Yuhara - Overt Haughtiness. Thus he suggests bringing a small inconspicuous sefer to learn from so as not to arouse attention. If this is not possible, one should try to think in learning.

Comment: Almost everyone doesn't agree that Yuhara doesn't apply anymore.

Comment: First of all, I think that the chattan & kallah notice very little of what the audience is doing. (I would hope that they don't pay any attention, but who knows?) Secondly, many weddings that I have attended really are a "waste of time" with the flower girls and all the extra relative marching down, and the choirs / singers, etc. It makes sense to learn, IMO.

Comment: See Targum Yonoson ben Uziel on [Devorim 6 (7)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9617&st=&pgnum=97) who translates בשבתך בביתך as 

במותביכון בבתיכון, בזמן מיעסוקכון בחיתונכון

when you sit in your house, when you are occupied with your marriage.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok could you please elaborate what your kovona is by citing these sources. I'm missing what your trying to say

Comment: Devorim 6 (7): And you shall teach them (=the words of the Torah) to your sons and speak of them "when you sit in your house", and when you walk on the way, and when you lie down and when you rise up. Targum Yonoson ben Uziel translates from the Hebrew for "when you sit in your house" as "when you sit in your house, when you are occupied with your marriages". So Targum Yonoson ben Uziel sees a need to study Torah at weddings. This cannot be when  gladdening the bride and groom because he is then occupied with a mitzvah and free from any other mitzvah , so it can only mean at the chupah!

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Is not washing the dishes being occupied with one's marriage?

Comment: @DoubleAA Right! It is indeed. This would be a way of learning at other people's marriages. The OP says "learn from a pocket sefer" which might be more difficult when washing the dishes than when standing around at a chuppah.